# Integral Convergence Help

Tags: calculus

I need some help in proving that the following integral is convergent.
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {e^x+x}}$$
I was trying to use the direct comparison test since $x>1$ and that $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {e^x}}>\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {e^x+x}}$$, but then I realized that the p-series test won't work on $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {e^x}}$$

So how exactly should I prove the convergence for the equation?

(Note: I'm not sure how to type out the infinity symbol so "inf" above represents positive infinity)

Comment: You can write $\infty$ by typing \infty between $s.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers suggest you to just integrate $\int_1^\infty e^{-x/2}$ dx, which is fine and correct! That what you should do.

However, if you wanted to use p-test like you asked, you can do the following:

$$ \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e^x + x}} dx \leq \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\bigg(1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots\bigg) + x } }dx \leq \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{x^3}{3!}}}  dx $$

which converges since $p = \dfrac{3}{2} > 1$.

Hopefully this offer you an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x}}=e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$, you know how to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Don't use the p-series test. Rather, compute the integral of $e^{-x/2}$ directly.